# Как записать строку в массив?

Tags: c, массивы, строки, указатели

В чем суть, как я понимаю, есть строка, которая и не строка совсем, как-будто указатель. Я хочу эту "строку-указатель" сунуть в массив, который назвала "otvet". НО вылезает ошибка **error: invalid operands to binary + (have 'char *' and 'char *')**.
Пожалуйста, поглядите на мой код, скажите, что я делаю не так, кроме как того, что занимаюсь программированием :)
Если интересно, задание: в стандартный поток ввода подается строка, состоящая из слов, длиной не более 100 символов. Слова состоят из латинских символов и разделены одним пробелом. Необходимо вывести в стандартный поток вывода строку, содержащую те же слова, но в обратном порядке.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
 
int main()
{
  
  char str[100];
  
  scanf("%100[^\n]", str);
  
  char *otvet[100];
  
  char *pch = strtok(str, " "); 
  
  
  int i = 0;
  while (pch != NULL && i<100) 
  {
      //printf("\n%s", pch);
      otvet[i] += pch;
      
      pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
      i++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Длина слова известна — 100, а их количество? Оно известно? Или хотя бы граница этого количества сверху?

Comment: 100 - это количество символов. "слов" может быть хоть 50, хоть 20, главное чтобы кол-во символов + пробелов не вышли за 100. По крайней мере, я так поняла.

Comment: возможные тесты:

Comment: Пример ввода 1:
mother father
Вывод:
father mother
Пример ввода 2:
aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg
Вывод:
ggg fff eee ddd ccc bbb aaa
Пример ввода 3:
Dkl alks aaasa
Вывод:
aaasa alks Dkl

Comment: Ну тогда массив из 50 (чтоб с запасом) указателей на `char`, считать всю строку, в массив — указатели на части от `strtok`, и собрать их в новую строку в обратном порядке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
 
int main()
{
  
  char str[100];
```

`str` это массив из 100 элементов типа `char`. Этот массив может хранить строку длиной до 99 символов (+ символ конца строки, `'\0'`).

```
  scanf("%100[^\n]", str);
```

`scanf()` считывает строку длиной до 100 символов. Т.е. на один символ больше, чем размер буфера. Это может привести к переполнению буфера.

```
  char *otvet[100];
```

`otvet` это массив из 100 указателей на `char`.

```
  char *pch = strtok(str, " "); 
  
  int i = 0;
  while (pch != NULL && i<100) 
  {
      //printf("\n%s", pch);
      otvet[i] += pch;
```

`otvet[i]` это i-тый указатель на `char` в массиве. `pch` это указатель на первый символ в i-том слове, т.е. тоже `char*`. Ты их тут складываешь.

> error: invalid operands to binary + (have 'char *' and 'char *')

Эта ошибка говорит, что нельзя складывать два указателя. Вместо этого, тебе нужно `otvet[i] = pch`, т.е. чтоб i-тый указатель в `otvet` указывал на i-тое слово.

```
      pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
      i++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

После этого `otvet[0]` содержит указатель на первый символ в первом слове, `otvet[1]` -- на второе слово и т.д. Тебе теперь нужно вывести слова из `otvet` в обратном порядке:

```
while (i > 0) {
    printf("%s ", otvet[--i]);
}
```

Немного картинки, при вводе "Hello world ABC" по окончании программы память выглядит примерно так:

```
str ->     H  e  l  l  o \0  w  o  r  l  d \0  A  B  C \0
           0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
           ^                 ^                 ^
           |                 |                 |
otvet[0] --/ == &str[0]      |                 |
otvet[1] --------------------/ == &str[6]      |
otvet[2] --------------------------------------/ == &str[12]

i == 3
```

Comment: спасибо вам большое, мало того, что все работает, так я еще и разобралась, что и как надо делать!